# How can I use returned variable in other function. Python

Tags: python, function, variables

For example I have a Python-code:

```
def fun():
     n = 100
     return n

def fun1():
    print(n)

fun()
fun1()
```

So I get an error: `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`. I also tried to make `n` global, but result was the same.

How can I use variable `n` from `fun` in `fun1`?

Comment: You never call `fun`, for starters. `fun1` should accept a parameter `n`, then you can do `fun1(fun())`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass parameter n to fun1, or call n from inside the function like Tim's answer

```
def fun():
     n = 100
     return n

def fun1(n):
    print(n)

fun1(fun())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `fun()` is never called and therefore never returns `n`. Try

```
def fun1():
    n = fun()
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable to store the return value of the function so that it can be used from the variable( n=fun() )

```
def fun():
     n = 100
     return n

def fun1():
    n=fun()
    print(n)

fun1()
```